# How to achieve this following design using twitter bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to design a responsive page like this

[image]

using margin and padding i tried to somehow match the design but failed...

here is the basic sample code i tried...

```
        <div class="container" style="border:1px solid red;">

            <div class="container col-lg-6" >
                <div class="row col-lg-12" style="border:1px solid brown;">
                    section1
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="row col-lg-12" style="border:1px solid brown;">
                section2
                </div>


            </div>

            <div class="container col-lg-6" >

                <div class="row col-lg-12" style="border:1px solid blue;">
                section3

                </div>


            </div>              

    </div>
```

I need some help.. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="well" style="height: 100px">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="well" style="height: 40px">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="well" style="height: 140px">
    </div>
</div>
```

It is just a demo. You can add border, height on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some negative margins to the left and right of your inner divs. Also, containers within containers is not good practice, and it gets messy on various browser sizes.

http://www.bootply.com/6FWRFHv62f

CSS

```
.n-margin{margin-left:-30px; margin-right:-30px;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container" style="border:1px solid red;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 n-margin">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="border:1px solid brown;height:200px;">
          section1
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="border:1px solid brown;height:60px">
          section2
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 n-margin pull-right">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="border:1px solid blue;height:260px">
          section3
        </div>
    </div>              
  </div>
```